# How to fix Preg_match () warning?

Tags: preg-match

I am using preg_match function to my program like this

```
(preg_match('/^(f|ht)tps?\://', $this->sourceFilename))
```

But it shows a warning like this

**`Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '/'`**

How can it modify? Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

The last slash should be escaped

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `/` inside the regexp:

```
preg_match('/^(f|ht)tps?:\//', $this->sourceFilename)
```

or use a different delimiter:

```
preg_match('#^(f|ht)tps?:/#', $this->sourceFilename)
```

BTW, you don't need to escape `:`.